# Error installing NLTK on Win 7

Tags: python, nltk

I try to install NLTK on my Win 7 computer. I am getting the following error message:

```
Python version -32 required, which was not found in the registry
```

I have done the following actions:

1. I have installed Python 32 Bit version 3.6.1.
2. On another computer I have installed Anaconda.
3. I have done the steps described in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nltk-users/sNuc1vBIfUc).

None of them works and I am still getting the error message when running the NLTk setup. Does anyone know what I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After three days of research finally I have solved the problem. So for anyone else to safe you the time I invested, do the following steps:
1. Install Anaconda 32 bit
2. After sucessfull installation run `python` and use the following command `import nltk`
3. Run the command `nltk.download()` (don't forget the parantheses)